# Change lang/region in Greeter

Tags: greeter, time

im actually living in tokyo and my system is setted to my native language (fr). But the format of day in the greeter are still in japanese like this 7月16.
Settings are only working for the session in the wingpanel (fr) but nothing change in the greeter.
How can i change it to fr?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in terminal:

```
localectl set-locale "LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

Comment: strange as it might be, it finally got updated after a few reboots over the days.
Thank you.